# Excel - How to check if sheet is protected in IF In-built function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

**Example 1:-**

Input :-

```
=IF(FALSE,NA(),"string")
```

Output :-

[image]

---

**Example 2**

Input :-

```
=IF(TRUE,NA(),"string")
```

Output :-

[image]

---

So as per example 1 & 2 instead of first argument [i.e. static argument FALSE or TRUE] I need to check that if it is protected sheet.

So output should be as per example 1 if the sheet is not protected and if sheet is protected the output should be as per example 2.

Comment: [`CELL`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) can return if the cell is locked. Not sure if you can get the sheet protection status using regular formulas.

Comment: CELL - Always gives "v" as output for protected and un-protected also [=CELL("type",A1)]

Comment: Please re-read the docs... `"type"` is not the correct argument.

Comment: You mean protect as type '=CELL("protect",A1)'?

Comment: Can you please paste an example here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use VBA, then consider this tiny VBA user defined function:

```
Public Function IsSheetProtected(s As String) As Boolean
    Application.Volatile
    IsSheetProtected = Sheets(s).ProtectContents
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using VBA. As I'm using officejs just trying to wrap this using in-built functions.